# What is the most responsive way to replace content of a QWidget that has a QVBoxLayout layout?

Tags: python, layout, pyqt5, responsive

I'm building a PyQt5 widget that will show search results.
The widget is a scroll area that has a vertical layout set to it, each item in it is a "search result" widget.
I want to update the list of widgets for each search result by clearing all the "search result" widgets, make new instances of "search result" that match my search and display them.
In my googling journey most of the suggestions I've seen are of the following format:

> Psuedo code:

```
while widgets in layout:
delete last item (by either setting parent to None, or calling deleteLater() )
```

All the proposed solutions I encountered share the same structure that doesn't seem optimal at all to me, wouldn't I get a more responsive result by deleting the layout and making a new one?

according to PyQt documentation, calling deleteLater() will also recursively schedule the children nodes for deletion when Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose attribute is set to True. I'm am still in very early stages of learning PyQt but I assume that using this will not block my code as opposed to looping through all the widgets in the layout.
And even if it's not so I can alternatively replace the current layout and take care of disposing the old one after I'm done initiating the new one.

to clarify a bit on my rambling, this is an example of a suggested approach that I saw:

```
for i in reversed(range(layout.count())): 
    layout.itemAt(i).widget().setParent(None)
```

And here is what I'm planning on using (where self is the scroll area widget):

```
self.layout.deleteLater()
self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
self.setLayout(self.layout)
```

This will leave me with more room to manage and schedule deleting the layout. Also I've read that neither setParent(None) or deleteLater() are ideal solutions in the sense that sometimes they present unexpected behavior like not actually clearing the widget references in the layout, so switching to a new instance of a layout should at least secure me consistency regarding that?

P.S. Is there a better performance wise (responsive, less memory/CPU usage) implementation that will not sacrifice the simplicity of the structure too much? My project is for a small lab inventory tracking, but if I ever have to scale it I feel like having thousands of search result widgets is not ideal. yes I could load x amount of results at a time, but other suggestions will be welcome :)

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Usually, item view with model/view structure is a good choice to display search results in small or large scale. Reference: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/modelview.html

Comment: @S.Nick - I'm having some trouble understanding why the code blocks I have are not enough. Yes my question comes from my work but I think it is abstract and contained in itself, so additional code is irrelevant. What  do you feel is missing and what would you add or change to make my post clearer?

Comment: @ToSimplicity - Thank you, sounds exactly like what I was looking for